# Prevent Cassandra Query benefiting from caching

Tags: python, cassandra, cql, cassandra-driver

I am attempting to get some metrics for my Cassandra cluster. As such, I want to see how queries perform when they are run the first time, without the benefit of caching. Is there a way to disable the cache on a per-query basis, and if there is not is it possible to disable it on a per-table basis?

For the table in question, it was created with the caching property

```
AND caching = {
    'keys' : 'NONE',
    'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'
}
```

but based on the output the later issues of the same query are obviously receiving caching benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the caching configuration in the table, that you have already done, you should ensure that in the *cassandra.yaml* configuration file, the value for `row_cache_size_in_mb` is zero (0). If you need to change this value keep in mind that you need to do the change in each node and restart them, one node at a time.

Comment: Why just altering the table is not enough? Whichever is smaller should win, no?